# Insert a new section to a binary file?

Tags: c, linux, nasm, elf

I try to coding a program to insert a empty (as the first step) phdr struct to any elf binary, so I coding like below:

cat add_phdr.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stddef.h>

static void calc_dyntables(void **ehdr_ptr, size_t bound_size)
{
    void *ptr = *ehdr_ptr;
    Elf32_Ehdr *Elf32_ptr = NULL;

    Elf32_ptr = (Elf32_Ehdr *)ptr;
    Elf32_Phdr *elf32_phdr = NULL;
    int n, found = 0;

    n = Elf32_ptr->e_phnum;
    elf32_phdr = ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_phoff;
    while (n--) {
        if (elf32_phdr->p_type == PT_DYNAMIC) {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
        elf32_phdr++;
    }

    if (found) {
        /* printf("=== PT_DYNAMIC: offset: 0x%x, size: 0x%x\n",  */
                /* elf32_phdr->p_offset, elf32_phdr->p_filesz); */
        /* printf("sizeof(Elf32_Dyn): %d\n", sizeof(Elf32_Dyn)); */
    }
    else
        return;

    /* list all of dynamic sections */
    found = 0;
    Elf32_Dyn *dyn_entry = ptr + elf32_phdr->p_offset;
    while (dyn_entry->d_tag != DT_NULL) {
        switch (dyn_entry->d_tag) {
            case 0x6ffffef5:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case 0x6ffffff0:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case 0x6ffffffe:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case 0x0000000c:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case 0x0000000d:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case 0x00000019:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case 0x0000001a:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case 0x00000005:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case 0x00000006:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case 0x00000003:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case 0x00000017:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case 0x00000011:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        /* printf("== tag: 0x%x, value: 0x%x\n", dyn_entry->d_tag, */
                /* dyn_entry->d_un.d_val); */
        dyn_entry++;
    }

}

static int write_phdr(int fd_dst, void *ptr, size_t filesize)
{
    /* ptr for Ehdr */
    Elf32_Ehdr *Elf32_ptr = NULL;
    Elf32_ptr = (Elf32_Ehdr *)ptr;

    /* ptr for Phdr */
    Elf32_Phdr *elf32_phdr = NULL;
    /* ptr for Shdr */
    Elf32_Shdr *elf32_shdr = NULL;

    int n;

    /*
     * We must find the phdr array's border, then recalcuate 
     * the offset of phdrs & shdrs which's offset beyond the
     * offset of border.
     */
    off_t old_phdr_border = Elf32_ptr->e_phoff + Elf32_ptr->e_phentsize * Elf32_ptr->e_phnum;
    printf("=== border 0x%x\n", (unsigned int) (0x8048000 + old_phdr_border));
    off_t phdr_size = Elf32_ptr->e_phentsize;

    /* recalcuate the hash table address */
    calc_dyntables(&ptr, phdr_size);
    /* pdhr */
    n = Elf32_ptr->e_phnum;
    elf32_phdr = ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_phoff;

    /* recalculate phdr offset */
    while (n-- > 0) {
        if (elf32_phdr->p_offset  >= old_phdr_border) {
            elf32_phdr->p_offset += phdr_size;
            elf32_phdr->p_vaddr += phdr_size;
            elf32_phdr->p_paddr += phdr_size;
        }
        else {
            if ((elf32_phdr->p_offset + elf32_phdr->p_filesz) >= old_phdr_border) {
                elf32_phdr->p_filesz += phdr_size;
                elf32_phdr->p_memsz += phdr_size;
            }
        }
        elf32_phdr++;
    }

    /* recalculate shdr offset */
    n = Elf32_ptr->e_shnum;
    elf32_shdr = ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_shoff;
    while (n-- > 0) {
        if (elf32_shdr->sh_offset >= old_phdr_border) {
            elf32_shdr->sh_offset += phdr_size;
            elf32_shdr->sh_addr += phdr_size;
        }
        else {
            if ((elf32_shdr->sh_offset + elf32_shdr->sh_size) >= old_phdr_border) {
                elf32_shdr->sh_size += phdr_size;
            }
        }
        elf32_shdr++;
    }

    Elf32_ptr->e_shoff += phdr_size;

    Elf32_Phdr *new_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));
    if (new_ptr == NULL)
        return -1;

    Elf32_ptr->e_phnum += 1;

    /* recalculate the entry */
    if (Elf32_ptr->e_entry > old_phdr_border)
        Elf32_ptr->e_entry += phdr_size;


    write(fd_dst, ptr, old_phdr_border);
    memset(new_ptr, 0, sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));
    new_ptr->p_type = PT_NULL;
    new_ptr->p_offset = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_vaddr = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_paddr = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_filesz = 0x1111;
    new_ptr->p_memsz = 0;
    new_ptr->p_flags = PF_R;
    new_ptr->p_align = 0x4;
    write(fd_dst, new_ptr, phdr_size);
    write(fd_dst, ptr + old_phdr_border, filesize - old_phdr_border);

    free(new_ptr);

    return 0;
}

/*
 * this version of write_phdr will apend phdr to
 * the tail of file, so it wont move any sections
 * or offset, we just need change the entry address.
 */
static int write_phdr2(int fd_dst, void *ptr, size_t filesize)
{
    /* ptr for Ehdr */
    Elf32_Ehdr *Elf32_ptr = NULL;
    Elf32_ptr = (Elf32_Ehdr *)ptr;

    /* ptr for Phdr */
//    Elf32_Phdr *elf32_phdr = NULL;

    Elf32_Phdr *new_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));
    if (new_ptr == NULL)
        return -1;

    off_t phdr_size = Elf32_ptr->e_phentsize;

    /* recalculate the entry */
//    Elf32_ptr->e_entry += phdr_size;

    write(fd_dst, ptr, filesize);

    /* append the phdr to the tail of file */
    memset(new_ptr, 0, sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));
    new_ptr->p_type = PT_NULL;
    new_ptr->p_offset = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_vaddr = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_paddr = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_filesz = 0;
    new_ptr->p_memsz = 0;
    new_ptr->p_flags = PF_R;
    new_ptr->p_align = 0x4;
    write(fd_dst, new_ptr, phdr_size);

    free(new_ptr);

    return 0;
}

/*
 * we'll add a new phdr to the binary file
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd_src, fd_dst;
    //size_t len = 0;
    size_t filesize = 0;
    void *ptr = NULL;   /* ptr to binary file which mapped in memory */
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s [ src bin ] [ dst bin ]...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*
     * we'll calculate the file size then map to memory
     */
    fd_src = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    if (fd_src < 0) {
        printf("Failed to open %s!\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fd_dst = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0755);

    if (fd_dst < 0) {
        printf("Failed to open %s!\n", argv[2]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* get file size with lseek SEEK_END */
    filesize = lseek(fd_src, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (filesize < 0) {
        perror("lseek failed!");
        close(fd_src);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr = mmap(0, filesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd_src, 0);
    if (ptr < 0) {
        perror("mmap failed!");
        close(fd_src);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (1)
    write_phdr(fd_dst, ptr, filesize);

    if (0)
    write_phdr2(fd_dst, ptr, filesize);

    /* copy the modified file to dst */
    /* do the clean work */
    munmap(ptr, filesize);
    close(fd_src);
    close(fd_dst);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

then the Makefile:

```
cat Makefile
CC  = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
LD  = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld
LDFLAGS = -m elf_i386
CFLAGS  = -m32 -Wall -fPIE

TARGETS = elf_parser show_addr without_libc add_phdr read_elf hello

all: $(TARGETS)

elf_parser:elf_parser.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

show_addr:show_addr.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

without_libc:without_libc.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -nostdlib -o $@ $<

add_phdr:add_phdr.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

hello:hello.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

read_elf:read_elf.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

read_elf.o:read_elf.asm
    nasm -f elf32 -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGETS)
    rm -rf *.o
```

OK, there are many other code include asm code, I just list the read_elf.asm and hello.c as comparison:
cat read_elf.asm:

```
    global _start
_start:
    call    main
    xor     eax, eax
    inc     eax
    xor     ebx, ebx
    int     0x80

main:
    call    funA
    ret

funA:
    call    funB
    ret
funB:
    call    funC
    ret
funC:
    push    byte 4
    pop     eax
    xor     ebx, ebx
    inc     ebx
    mov     ecx, 0x08048001
    push    byte 3
    pop     edx
    int     0x80
    ret
```

cat hello.c:

```
int main()
{
    return 10;
}
```

Next, let's compile the codes, then run add_phdr program:

```
./add_phdr read_elf test
```

then run the test, it works well, but when I try to patch the hello program like below:

```
./add_phdr hello hello_test
./hello_test
```

I got this:

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 876: _dl_setup_hash: Assertion `(bitmask_nwords & (bitmask_nwords - 1)) == 0' failed!
```

I could not run it any more!
So any tips?

**Update:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stddef.h>

static void calc_symtab(void **ehdr_ptr, size_t bound_size)
{
    void *ptr = *ehdr_ptr;
    Elf32_Shdr *shdr_ptr = NULL;
    Elf32_Ehdr *Elf32_ptr = (Elf32_Ehdr *)ptr;


    int n = Elf32_ptr->e_shnum;
    char *shstrtab = NULL;

    /*
     * first of all, let's get the shstrtab, we'll get 
     * the name of each section with it
     */
    shdr_ptr = (Elf32_Shdr *)(ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_shoff);
    while (n--) {
        if (shdr_ptr->sh_type == SHT_STRTAB) {
            shstrtab = (char *)(ptr + shdr_ptr->sh_offset);
            if (!strcmp(&shstrtab[shdr_ptr->sh_name], ".shstrtab"))
                break;
        }
        shdr_ptr++;
    }

    /* list all of sections */
    shdr_ptr = (Elf32_Shdr *)(ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_shoff);
    n = Elf32_ptr->e_shnum;
    while (n--) {
        if (shdr_ptr->sh_type == SHT_SYMTAB) {
            int n2 = (shdr_ptr->sh_size / sizeof(Elf32_Sym)); 
            Elf32_Sym *sym = (Elf32_Sym *)(ptr + shdr_ptr->sh_offset);
            while (n2--) {
                if (sym->st_value > 0)
                    sym->st_value += bound_size;
                sym++;
            }
        }
        shdr_ptr++;
    }
}

static void calc_dynsym(void **ehdr_ptr, size_t bound_size)
{
    void *ptr = *ehdr_ptr;
    Elf32_Shdr *shdr_ptr = NULL;
    Elf32_Ehdr *Elf32_ptr = (Elf32_Ehdr *)ptr;


    int n = Elf32_ptr->e_shnum;
    char *shstrtab = NULL;

    /*
     * first of all, let's get the shstrtab, we'll get 
     * the name of each section with it
     */
    shdr_ptr = (Elf32_Shdr *)(ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_shoff);
    while (n--) {
        if (shdr_ptr->sh_type == SHT_STRTAB) {
            shstrtab = (char *)(ptr + shdr_ptr->sh_offset);
            if (!strcmp(&shstrtab[shdr_ptr->sh_name], ".shstrtab"))
                break;
        }
        shdr_ptr++;
    }

    /* list all of sections */
    shdr_ptr = (Elf32_Shdr *)(ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_shoff);
    n = Elf32_ptr->e_shnum;
    while (n--) {
        if (shdr_ptr->sh_type == SHT_DYNSYM) {
            int n2 = (shdr_ptr->sh_size / sizeof(Elf32_Sym)); 
            Elf32_Sym *sym = (Elf32_Sym *)(ptr + shdr_ptr->sh_offset);
            while (n2--) {
                if (sym->st_value > 0)
                    sym->st_value += bound_size;
                sym++;
            }
        }
        shdr_ptr++;
    }
}

static void calc_relocs(void **ehdr_ptr, size_t bound_size)
{
    void *ptr = *ehdr_ptr;
    Elf32_Shdr *shdr_ptr = NULL;
    Elf32_Ehdr *Elf32_ptr = (Elf32_Ehdr *)ptr;


    int n = Elf32_ptr->e_shnum;
    char *shstrtab = NULL;

    /*
     * first of all, let's get the shstrtab, we'll get 
     * the name of each section with it
     */
    shdr_ptr = (Elf32_Shdr *)(ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_shoff);
    while (n--) {
        if (shdr_ptr->sh_type == SHT_STRTAB) {
            shstrtab = (char *)(ptr + shdr_ptr->sh_offset);
            if (!strcmp(&shstrtab[shdr_ptr->sh_name], ".shstrtab"))
                break;
        }
        shdr_ptr++;
    }

    /* list all of sections */
    shdr_ptr = (Elf32_Shdr *)(ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_shoff);
    n = Elf32_ptr->e_shnum;
    while (n--) {
        if (shdr_ptr->sh_type == SHT_REL || shdr_ptr->sh_type == SHT_RELA) {

            int n2 = (shdr_ptr->sh_size / sizeof(Elf32_Rel)); 
            Elf32_Rel *rel = (Elf32_Rel *)(ptr + shdr_ptr->sh_offset);
            while (n2--) {
                rel->r_offset += bound_size;
                rel++;
            }
        }
        shdr_ptr++;
    }
}

static void calc_dyntables(void **ehdr_ptr, size_t bound_size)
{
    void *ptr = *ehdr_ptr;
    Elf32_Ehdr *Elf32_ptr = NULL;

    Elf32_ptr = (Elf32_Ehdr *)ptr;
    Elf32_Phdr *elf32_phdr = NULL;
    int n, found = 0;

    n = Elf32_ptr->e_phnum;
    elf32_phdr = ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_phoff;
    while (n--) {
        if (elf32_phdr->p_type == PT_DYNAMIC) {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
        elf32_phdr++;
    }

    if (found) {
        /* printf("=== PT_DYNAMIC: offset: 0x%x, size: 0x%x\n",  */
                /* elf32_phdr->p_offset, elf32_phdr->p_filesz); */
        /* printf("sizeof(Elf32_Dyn): %d\n", sizeof(Elf32_Dyn)); */
    }
    else
        return;

    /* list all of dynamic sections */
    found = 0;
    Elf32_Dyn *dyn_entry = ptr + elf32_phdr->p_offset;
    while (dyn_entry->d_tag != DT_NULL) {
        switch (dyn_entry->d_tag) {
            case DT_GNU_HASH:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case DT_VERSYM:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case DT_VERNEED:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case DT_INIT:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case DT_FINI:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case DT_INIT_ARRAY:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case DT_FINI_ARRAY:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case DT_STRTAB:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case DT_SYMTAB:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case DT_PLTGOT:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case DT_JMPREL:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            case DT_REL:
                dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        /* printf("== tag: 0x%x, value: 0x%x\n", dyn_entry->d_tag, */
                /* dyn_entry->d_un.d_val); */
        dyn_entry++;
    }

}

static int write_phdr(int fd_dst, void *ptr, size_t filesize)
{
    /* ptr for Ehdr */
    Elf32_Ehdr *Elf32_ptr = NULL;
    Elf32_ptr = (Elf32_Ehdr *)ptr;

    /* ptr for Phdr */
    Elf32_Phdr *elf32_phdr = NULL;
    /* ptr for Shdr */
    Elf32_Shdr *elf32_shdr = NULL;

    int n;

    /*
     * We must find the phdr array's border, then recalcuate 
     * the offset of phdrs & shdrs which's offset beyond the
     * offset of border.
     */
    off_t old_phdr_border = Elf32_ptr->e_phoff + Elf32_ptr->e_phentsize * Elf32_ptr->e_phnum;
    printf("=== border 0x%x\n", (unsigned int) (0x8048000 + old_phdr_border));
    off_t phdr_size = Elf32_ptr->e_phentsize;

    /* recalcuate the hash table address */
    calc_dyntables(&ptr, phdr_size);
    calc_relocs(&ptr, phdr_size);
    calc_symtab(&ptr, phdr_size);
    calc_dynsym(&ptr, phdr_size);
    /* pdhr */
    n = Elf32_ptr->e_phnum;
    elf32_phdr = ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_phoff;

    /* recalculate phdr offset */
    while (n-- > 0) {
        if (elf32_phdr->p_offset  >= old_phdr_border) {
            elf32_phdr->p_offset += phdr_size;
            elf32_phdr->p_vaddr += phdr_size;
            elf32_phdr->p_paddr += phdr_size;
        }
        else {
            if ((elf32_phdr->p_offset + elf32_phdr->p_filesz) >= old_phdr_border) {
                elf32_phdr->p_filesz += phdr_size;
                elf32_phdr->p_memsz += phdr_size;
            }
        }
        elf32_phdr++;
    }

    /* recalculate shdr offset */
    n = Elf32_ptr->e_shnum;
    elf32_shdr = ptr + Elf32_ptr->e_shoff;
    while (n-- > 0) {
        if (elf32_shdr->sh_offset >= old_phdr_border) {
            elf32_shdr->sh_offset += phdr_size;
            if (elf32_shdr->sh_addr > 0)
                elf32_shdr->sh_addr += phdr_size;
        }
        else {
            if ((elf32_shdr->sh_offset + elf32_shdr->sh_size) >= old_phdr_border) {
                elf32_shdr->sh_size += phdr_size;
            }
        }
        elf32_shdr++;
    }

    Elf32_ptr->e_shoff += phdr_size;

    Elf32_Phdr *new_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));
    if (new_ptr == NULL)
        return -1;

    Elf32_ptr->e_phnum += 1;

    /* recalculate the entry */
    if (Elf32_ptr->e_entry >= old_phdr_border)
        Elf32_ptr->e_entry += phdr_size;


    write(fd_dst, ptr, old_phdr_border);
    memset(new_ptr, 0, sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));
    new_ptr->p_type = PT_NULL;
    new_ptr->p_offset = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_vaddr = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_paddr = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_filesz = 0x1111;
    new_ptr->p_memsz = 0;
    new_ptr->p_flags = PF_R;
    new_ptr->p_align = 0x4;
    write(fd_dst, new_ptr, phdr_size);
    write(fd_dst, ptr + old_phdr_border, filesize - old_phdr_border);

    free(new_ptr);

    return 0;
}

/*
 * this version of write_phdr will apend phdr to
 * the tail of file, so it wont move any sections
 * or offset, we just need change the entry address.
 */
static int write_phdr2(int fd_dst, void *ptr, size_t filesize)
{
    /* ptr for Ehdr */
    Elf32_Ehdr *Elf32_ptr = NULL;
    Elf32_ptr = (Elf32_Ehdr *)ptr;

    /* ptr for Phdr */
//    Elf32_Phdr *elf32_phdr = NULL;

    Elf32_Phdr *new_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));
    if (new_ptr == NULL)
        return -1;

    off_t phdr_size = Elf32_ptr->e_phentsize;

    /* recalculate the entry */
//    Elf32_ptr->e_entry += phdr_size;

    write(fd_dst, ptr, filesize);

    /* append the phdr to the tail of file */
    memset(new_ptr, 0, sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));
    new_ptr->p_type = PT_NULL;
    new_ptr->p_offset = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_vaddr = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_paddr = 0xffff;
    new_ptr->p_filesz = 0;
    new_ptr->p_memsz = 0;
    new_ptr->p_flags = PF_R;
    new_ptr->p_align = 0x4;
    write(fd_dst, new_ptr, phdr_size);

    free(new_ptr);

    return 0;
}

/*
 * we'll add a new phdr to the binary file
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd_src, fd_dst;
    //size_t len = 0;
    size_t filesize = 0;
    void *ptr = NULL;   /* ptr to binary file which mapped in memory */
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s [ src bin ] [ dst bin ]...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*
     * we'll calculate the file size then map to memory
     */
    fd_src = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    if (fd_src < 0) {
        printf("Failed to open %s!\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fd_dst = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0755);

    if (fd_dst < 0) {
        printf("Failed to open %s!\n", argv[2]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* get file size with lseek SEEK_END */
    filesize = lseek(fd_src, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (filesize < 0) {
        perror("lseek failed!");
        close(fd_src);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr = mmap(0, filesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd_src, 0);
    if (ptr < 0) {
        perror("mmap failed!");
        close(fd_src);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (1)
    write_phdr(fd_dst, ptr, filesize);

    if (0)
    write_phdr2(fd_dst, ptr, filesize);

    /* copy the modified file to dst */
    /* do the clean work */
    munmap(ptr, filesize);
    close(fd_src);
    close(fd_dst);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Well, just to make sure.  It could be that `test` is an unfortunate name for your target executable, as it coincides with a standard Linux  command. Are you running it with `./test`? Could you try naming it differently?  I think it works OK on my PC.

Comment: Sorry, ./test just a arbitrary name, nothing special, I just name it as output result, thanks!

Comment: If you also get the same problem using a different name, instead of `test`, then please help us by telling what you expect to happen and what actually happens.  On my PC, both `read_elf` and `test` output `"ELF"` and exit normally.

Comment: read_elf.asm is just a comparison, I need it to work when I patch hello with add_phdr, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So any tips?

ELF format has many pointers inside of it, and if you move data around (as your program does), you *must* adjust all of these pointers to point to new location/offset (which your program fails to do).

ELF is really not designed for the kinds of post-link processing you are trying to perform.

Your *immediate* problem is that `hello` contains a `DT_HASH` or `DT_GNU_HASH` (or both), that still point to the old offset of `.hash` or `.gnu.hash` section, but you've moved the bits around, and so the old offset no longer contains a valid hash table that the runtime loader expects to find there.

Running

```
for exe in hello hello_test; do
  readelf -d $exe | grep HASH
  readelf -WS $exe | grep hash
done
```

should prove that this is indeed the case.

**EDIT**:

> ```
> case 0x6ffffef5:
>            dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
>            break;
> ```

Don't ever do that: it makes your code impossible to read and understand. Do this instead:

```
#include <elf.h>
...
  case DT_GNU_HASH:
            dyn_entry->d_un.d_ptr += bound_size;
            break;
```

Since you have 12 such cases, I refuse to map them back to their symbolic names.

In any case, my answer stands: you are not updating *some* pointer somewhere, which makes your resulting ELF self-inconsistent, which makes the dynamic loader unhappy.

If you really want to persist in this direction, install glibc debug symbols, and debug the loader like this:

```
gdb /path/to/ld-linux.so ./hello_test
```

That should allow you to identify *which* pointer you've failed to update.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will have a try!

Comment: You are right, I update the dynamic tables, it's OK, readelf does not complain any more, but I still can not run the modified binary.

Comment: I have tried a lot, see the UPDATE of my code, fix many values, you can diff the hello with its modified version, I changed the values/address of sections/tables etc, but it still does not work, so may be I walk into a wrong way, may be the code has a fix address in compile time, so may be I need to tell the code of changing, but thank you for your tips, again!

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the new executable using "readelf"?

I myself would check if the phdr is (already) at the end of the file (phoff + phentsize * phnum == file_size). If no I'd simply append a copy of the phdr table to the end of the file and modify the phoff member in the elf header.

Then I can append phdr sections at the end of the file (and I do not have to move sections).

The original phdr table would remain in the file but be inactive.

Comment: Good idea, I will have a try, but I want the answer to insert new phdr, I want to known why it does not work?